# How to avoid Tostring exception if string is null?

Tags: c#, datareader

I want to convert the data row value to sring as follows.

```
userGuid = dr["user_guid"].ToString();
```

It may contains Guid or null(Not string empty). If it contains null i got the exception.

How can i overcome this..

Comment: @AndroidNoobie I try that it works for empty string.But for null it does not working

Comment: Hey mate, look up the null safe navigation operator

Comment: There are lot of examples, for example `dr["user_guid"]?.ToString();`.

Comment: @Andrew What is the meant by null safe navigation operator

Comment: @SeM Please provide some examples

Comment: See the example from SeM.https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jerrynixon/2014/02/26/at-last-c-is-getting-sometimes-called-the-safe-navigation-operator/

Comment: Can you please check if it is **null** or **DBNull**?

Comment: @Down voter Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are reading from data reader.

You will have to check if the value is null or DBNull and then you can call to string method.

```
    string user_guid = dr["user_guid"] != DBNull.Value && dr["user_guid"] != null ? dr["user_guid"].ToString() : null ;
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (dr[user_guid"] != null) {
    //whatever you want to do
} else {
    //handle the null value in some way
}
```

Alternatively,

```
dr["user_guid"]?.ToString();
```

The ? is what's called a "null-safe navigator".

Comment: I try this also i want to use this conversion in many places. So this  lead too much of code.I want simple solutions

Comment: This is a simple solution. If a standard check for a null value is too much, I'm not sure what exactly you could possibly be expecting.

Comment: I know this is simple question.I just want to done this by single line of code or by overriding in only one place

Answer (score 0):

This might be useful, one of many ways

```
 userGuid  = dr["user_guid"]?.ToString()?? "Default Value";
```

Please do replace "Default Value" with whatever you feel is appropriate according to your application logic.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this:
`userGuid = dr["user_guid"].ToString() ?? throw new Exception();`

Comment: He wants to avoid exceptions.

Comment: Sorry. No problem.
`userGuid = dr["user_guid"].ToString() ?? "";`

Comment: No worries mate.